# How Do I Randomize Where My Ball Collides With The Paddle? Pong Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

so I was wondering how I could randomize where my ball collides with the paddle
instead of just going on the same direction [video](https://gyazo.com/a278b8518a6a00ff1f738b1924c55c78) the ball is just looping throw the same direction

```
    if ball1.rect.colliderect(playerman) or ball1.rect.colliderect(playerman2):
        ball1.velx *= -1
```

this is my balls movement

```
    ball1.x += ball1.velx
    ball1.y += ball1.yvel
    if ball1.x <= 0 or ball1.x >= height:
        ball1.velx *= -1
    if ball1.y <= 0 or ball1.y >= width:
        ball1.yvel *= -1
    ball1.rect.x = ball1.x
    ball1.rect.y = ball1.y
```

and its class:

```
class ball:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x =x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width  = width
        self.color = color
        self.velx = 5
        self.yvel = 5
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.circle(window, self.color, self.rect.center,10)


ball1 = ball(290,200,20,20,white)
```

Comment: You could randomize the initial velocity for the ball, within a specific range. Additionally, you could change how paddle collision works, maybe making the bounced ball's velocity rely upon distance from the center of the paddle (similarly to [Breakout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakout_(video_game)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility to get some randomness, is to slightly change `yvel` when the ball hits a paddle.
Compute a random value in a certain range (e.g. `random.randint(-3, 3)`) and add it to `yvel`.
Ensure that the amount of `yvel` is always less than the amount of `velx`:

```py
if ball1.rect.colliderect(playerman) or ball1.rect.colliderect(playerman2):
    ball1.velx *= -1

    vel_change = random.randint(-3, 3)

    ball1.velx += vel_change
    ball1.velx = max(-abs(ball1.yvel), min(abs(ball1.yvel), ball1.velx))
```

If you use floating point values then use `random.uniform()` rather than `random.randint()`:

<s>`vel_change = random.randint(-3, 3)`</s>

```py
vel_change = random.uniform(-3, 3)
```